# php set top property different after every 3 div dynamically

Tags: php, css

I want to set the css TOP property different after every 3 div's

for eg:

```
<div style="top:100px;">
</div>
<div style="top:100px;">
</div>
<div style="top:100px;">
</div>
**Now after this the next 3 div's shall have**
<div style="top:150px;">
</div>
<div style="top:150px;">
</div>
<div style="top:150px;">
</div>
**Now after this the next 3 div's shall have**
<div style="top:200px;">
</div>
<div style="top:200px;">
</div>
<div style="top:200px;">
</div>
**and so on**
```

I want to do this dynamically using php.
Using the for loop i can check if

```
$ij=0; if($ij%3==0) {
    echo "";
    }
    else {
    }
```

But not sure how to get desired result.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Is the number of divs static or dynamic? If dynamic, how are you pulling them in?

Comment: Do you need to increment `top` property should after every 3 div's?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$top = 50;
$n = 30; // no. of divs
for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
    if($i % 3==0) $top+=50;
    echo "<div style=\"top:".$top."px;\">\n</div>";
}
```